# How to correct sql statement to give correct result

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm running a local MySQL Server on port 3306 with a schema "sys" featuring a table "users" [image: Table in sys schema]

Now I have a small spring boot application to query all entries from that table.
Model for that table is:

```
package com.example.databaseneu.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Users {

@Id
// @Column(name = "id")
private int id;
// @Column(name = "name")
private String name;
// @Column(name = "salary")
private int salary;
// @Column(name = "team_name")
private String team_name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getTeam_name() {
    return team_name;
}

public void setTeam_name(String team_name) {
    this.team_name = team_name;
}}
```

The connection works, but the query doesnt seem to deliver the right result as I get the Whitelabel Error Page.
Query to get all elements from the table (autogenerated by repository)

```
Hibernate: 
select
    users0_.id as id1_0_,
    users0_.name as name2_0_,
    users0_.salary as salary3_0_,
    users0_.team_name as team_nam4_0_ 
from
    users users0_
```

So I'm uncertain if i defined the Entity wrong or something else alltogether
@Column Tag doesnt do the trick.

---Edit---

```
package com.example.databaseneu.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.databaseneu.model.Users;
import com.example.databaseneu.repository.UserRepository;

@Controller // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam int salary,
        @RequestParam String team_name) {
    Users n = new Users();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setSalary(salary);
    n.setTeam_name(team_name);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public Iterable<Users> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}}
```

So id navigate to localhost:8080/demo/all

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where you are doing the `repository.findAll()` ? Also the handler mapping i.e. `@RequestMapping / @GetMapping` part of your code. You might need to access that handler to view the JSON response.

Comment: Hope the edit is sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written all correct expect for one thing. Mark your return-type with `@ResponseBody` annotation -- similar to your `addNewUser` method.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Users> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}}
```

Hopefully this should work. If you still face issues, post it here.